# Sequelize - different included table names between dev/build mode

Tags: javascript, heroku, sequelize.js, next.js

I have a problem with included table names between dev mode and build mode.
I am using - Next.js, Heroku, MySQL.

This example is working fine in **development** mode.

```
export const getUserByEmail = async (email: string) => {
  const { users, positions, roles } = model

  return await users.findOne({
    where: {
      email: email,
      deleted: 0
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: positions,
        attributes: ['name']
      },
      {
        model: roles,
        attributes: ['name']
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Data what I get in **dev** mode:

```
{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'Alice',
  lastName: 'Bob',
  position: { 
    name: 'superadmin' 
  },
  role: { 
    name: 'Superadmin' 
  }
}
```

Strange behavior comes with **build** mode, where I get following data:

```
{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'Alice',
  lastName: 'Bob',
  positions_position: { 
    name: 'superadmin' 
  },
  roles_role: { 
    name: 'Superadmin' 
  }
}
```

Can be problem in defined model? I am totally confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding aliases to every relations between tables.

Example:

```
users.belongsTo(roles, { foreignKey: 'idRole', as: 'role' })
roles.hasMany(users, { foreignKey: 'idRole', as: 'roles' })
```

Then add the alias to selection:

```
include: [
  ...
  {
    model: roles,
    attributes: ['name'],
    as: 'role'
  }
]
```

Anyway, this is strange behavior...